# Inherit parent/container's width(panel's width) in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jpanel, width

I have created a JPanel (panelParent in the code) in Java with BoxLayout.
I have created another panel named "panelChild" and i add it in panelParent(parent).
I noticed that panelChild doesn't inherit the width of it's container(parent).

```
    JPanel panelParent = new JPanel();
    panelParent.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelParent, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

When i try to add a JList in "panelParent" i do:

```
    JList list;
    DefaultListModel listModel;
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    listModel.addElement("element1");
    listModel.addElement("element2");
    list = new JList(listModel);

    JPanel panelChild = new JPanel();        
    panelChild.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    panelChild.setBackground( Color.blue );
    panelChild.setAlignmentX( Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );
    panelParent.add(panelChild);
```

I noticed that panelChild does not inherit the width of its panelParent.
Is there any way in order to accomplish that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in my problem and it worked.

I did the following:

```
    panelChild.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

After that line of code, the childPanel had the same width as the container's
width.